# Java: Regex Verify an URL

Tags: java, regex, url

I want to verify the syntax of a URL. How should I use regexes to test the validity of a URL like `www.chaine.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, without regex:

```
public boolean validateURI(String uri)
{
    try
    {
        new URI(uri);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false; // MalformedURI Exception, is the name I think
    }
}
```

`URL extends URI`, you can say, I think...